# How to parsing HTML content at MFC, C++

Tags: html, parsing, mfc, dialog

I am a newbie working on MFC, C++,
Main works is load html file and display every content at MFC dialog.
When we click Hyperlink on dialog , it create new dialog/window to display file content(pdf) using window default assignment.
Is there any way that support extracts html content and write to MFC dialog?
If we do not use "Navigate"?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `CHtmlView`. Call `Navigate()` to start page loading and parse inside `OnDocumentComplete`. I'm sure you will find tons of examples on the Internet.

Comment: How to handle event when clicked on hyperlink, href on dialog, it will open in new dialog/new window?
Thanks in advance